# How to highlight text which is hidden under ... due to text-overflow:ellipsis

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im implementing a highlight word functionality based on keyword in the search.

[image: Screenshot of application]

So based on the keyword im replacing the content with span tag  and adding class as "highlighted-text"

```
 value = value.replace(RegularExpression, `<span class="highlight-text">${value.match(re)[0]}</span>`);
```

CSS for highlighted-text

```
.highlighted-text{
  background:yellow;
 }
```

and im also using this css to achieve clipping of text with 3 dots. As you can see in picture below.

```
 .message{
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
            white-space: nowrap;
            overflow: hidden;
       }
```

[image]

So its working fine

[image]

But let me search for word which is hidden inside clipped text ie. "..." like "hockey"

[image]

So its not showing up as its hidden. I want to show the user correctly  highlighted text with its before text and after text to some limit.Is there any ideal way we can achieve this is in javascript or  css?

Comment: outside what?...

Comment: You could clone the span and show the clone where ever you want.

Comment: I guess you mean in the browser. I don't think there is a trivial way. I don't think you know from JS if the text is actually clipping or not, or if the selection is in the clipped out text. I would suggest changing the style momentarily to `overflow scroll`. Alternatively, break the string into 3 sections around the selection and set overflow style on the outer 2 only?

Comment: can you describe your method of searching. ctrl+f? programmatically?

Comment: @all please review the question.I updated the question with screenshots

Comment: Maybe try to prepare a method that searches for a keyword and displays only a few words that appear before and after it. Display the prepared text instead of the beginning of the description.
So it could display: "_... and i love playing **hockey**_"

Comment: I would like to see the logic that is searching for text.  Can you please include this logic, as that will be where the fix needs to be put?